# Tools to view/solve Windows XP memory fragmentation

Tags: java, windows, memory, memory-management, windows-xp

We have a java program that requires a large amount of heap space - we start it with (among other command line arguments) the argument -Xmx1500m, which specifies a maximum heap space of 1500 MB. When starting this program on a Windows XP box that has been freshly rebooted, it will start and run without issues. But if the program has run several times, the computer has been up for a while, etc., when it tries to start I get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I suspect that Windows itself is suffering from memory fragmentation, but I don't know how to confirm this suspicion. At the time that this happens, Task manager and sysinternals procexp report 2000MB free memory. I have looked at [this question related to internal fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871/how-to-solve-memory-fragmentation)

So the first question is, How do I confirm my suspicion?
The second question is, if my suspicions are correct, does anyone know of any tools to solve this problem? I've looked around quite a bit, but I haven't found anything that helps, other than periodic reboots of the machine.

ps - changing operating systems is also not currently a viable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Torlack, a lot of this is because other DLLs are getting loaded and go into certain spots, breaking up the amount of memory you can get for the VM in one big chunk.

You can do some work on WinXP if you have more than 3G of memory to get some of the windows stuff moved around, look up PAE here:
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/server/PAE/PAEdrv.mspx

Your best bet, if you really need more than 1.2G of memory for your java app, is to look at 64 bit windows or linux or OSX.  If you're using any kind of native libraries with your app you'll have to recompile them for 64 bit, but its going to be a lot easier than trying to rebase dlls and stuff to maximize the memory you can get on 32 bit windows.

Another option would be to split your program up into multiple VMs and have them communicate with eachother via RMI or messaging or something.  That way each VM can have some subset of the memory you need.  Without knowing what your app does, i'm not sure that this will help in any way, though...

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are running out of page file space, this issue isn't that the computer is running out of memory.  The whole point of virtual memory is to allow the processes to use more virtual memory than is physically available.

Not knowing how the JVM handles the heap, it is a bit hard to say exactly what the problem is, but one of the common issues is that there isn't enough contiguous free address space available in your process to allow the heap to be extended.  Why this would be a problem after the machine has been running a while is a bit confusing.

I've been working on a similar problem at work.  I have found that running the program using WinDBG and using the "!address" and "!address -summary" commands have been invaluable in tracking down why a processes' virtual address space has become fragmented.  You can also try running the program after reboot and using the "!address" command to take a picture of the address space and then do the same when the program no longer runs.  This might clue you in on the problem.  Maybe something simple as an extra DLL getting loading might cause the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is Windows memory fragmentation. There is another question here on StackOverflow called [Java Maximum Memory on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp) that mentions using Process Explorer to look at where DLLs are mapped into memory, and then to address the problem by rebasing the DLLs so that load into memory in a more compact way.

Answer (score 0):

Using Minimem (http://minimem.kerkia.net/) for that application might fix your problem. However, I'm not sure this is the answer you are looking for. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider to start the program and reserving the memory and not
end the VM after each run. Look for different GC options and release your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use vmmap from Microsoft's SysInternals tools to view the fragmentation of the virtual address space, and identify what's breaking up the space