# JBoss6 fails to start on Windows (32bit) machine with JDK 7

Tags: java, java-7, jboss6.x, jvm-arguments

JBoss will not start with my current configuration. I receive the error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>   Press any key to continue . . .

The JAVA_OPTS being used by JBoss are:

```
-client 
-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat 
-Xms128 
-Xmx2G 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman 
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx2048m 
-XX:PermSize=32m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-Xss2m 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
-Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.MessageFactoryImpl 
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConnectionFactor‌​yImpl 
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl"
```

Comment: You question is impossible to answer without more detail - how are you trying to run JBoss (from a command-line, in an IDE, etc) and what VM options have been set, specifically the heap and perm-gen sizes

Comment: I am trying to run JBoss (from bin directory and then double click on standalone-full.bat file).

Comment: #Nick Holt, I don't know how to set VM options specifically the head and perm-gen sizes, please advice me.

Comment: JAVA_OPTS: "-client -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128 -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xss2m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.MessageFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `JAVA_OPTS` you're setting the maximum heap to 2048m (2G) which won't work on a Win32 - it's the `-Xmx2048m` option that controls this (which seems to be being set twice).

To run on a Win32 you should adjust the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options.   On a vanilla JBoss installation (well on my JBoss installation at least) both options are set in `standalone.conf.bat`.  Try setting both to `1024m` to start with and reduce if you're still having problems.

It's also likely that you'll want to turn down the -XX:MaxPermSize (which again is being set twice).  `256m` may work but if not try using `128m`.

Comment: Good spot on some of the arguments being set twice. @Z.I.J You'll want to tidy that up.

Comment: Currently in jboss batch file is:                                                                 
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=32m :
I have changed into 
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=32m
now working fine.

thanks Nick Holt and Mikaveli

Answer (score 1):

To reuse portions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533056/575766) answer of mine (about Tomcat, but applies to JBoss or any Java process):

> The Windows OS
>   limits the memory allocation of a 32-bit process to 2 GiB in total (by
>   default).
>
> [You will only be able] to allocate around 1.5 GiB heap
>   space because there is also other memory allocated to the process
>   (the JVM / library overhead, perm gen space etc.).
>
> [Why does 32-bit Windows impose a 2 GB process address space limit, but
>   64-bit Windows impose a 4GB limit?](https://superuser.com/questions/372498/why-does-32-bit-windows-impose-a-2-gb-process-address-space-limit-but-64-bit-wi)
>
> Other modern operating systems [cough Linux] allow 32-bit processes to
>   use all (or most) of the 4 GiB addressable space.
>
> That said, 64-bit Windows OS's can be configured to increase the limit
>   of 32-bit processes to 4 GiB (3 GiB on 32-bit):
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx
>
> However [as others have stated], the best solution is to use a 64-bit
>   JVM with your 64-bit OS. Terabyte heaps anyone? :D

So, you won't be able to set `-Xmx2048m` in your Java opts, but `-Xmx1024m` will work - as should a value approaching 1.5 GiB (but the exact figure varies).

Comment: Currently in jboss batch file is: set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=32m : I have changed into set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=32m now working fine

Answer (score 0):

You should use 64-bit OS. you will face a lot of problems with 32-bit OS while working on jboss6, jdk1.7 etc...

Comment: Is upgrade your PC and OS really an answer?  A Win32 will still afford you a 2GB process, which will be more than capable of running a JVM with a 1GB heap.  There's a likely to be something else wrong if JBoss won't fit in that

Comment: nwzhaider you mean we can't configure on 32bit window machine.

Comment: I have not choice to update OS 32bit to 64bit.. please help to configure jboss6 on 32bit machine.

Comment: @nwzhaider Including why they should use a 64-bit OS beyond "facing problems" would improve the value of this answer.