# Tomcat 7 64bit maximum memory usage

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'm using tomcat7 32 bit. As I know, it maybe manages maximum 1GB memory usage. I used caching data (ehcache) in my application, and sometimes it causes error "OutOfMemory", the application isn't working. I'm planning to use tomcat7 64bit to increase memory, but I don't know how many GBs does it manage in maximum? How do we configure to change memory of tomcat?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The maximum amount of memory is not 'restricted' by tomcat, it is restricted by the JVM + System Architecture / OS.

See these questions/answers for more info:

- [Increasing the JVM maximum heap size for memory intensive applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030263/increasing-the-jvm-maximum-heap-size-for-memory-intensive-applications)
- [Max memory for 64bit Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093679/max-memory-for-64bit-java)

This means that you will have to install a 64 bit java runtime environment (and not a 64 bit tomcat).
Then adapt the -Xmx settings in your tomcat startup scripts.
See e.g.:

- [Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory#Q1)
- [Adjusting Memory Settings for Tomcat](http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/Adjusting+Memory+Settings+for+Tomcat)

=== Edit
Sorry I was a bit outdated, there is a prepackaged Tomcat7 64 bit all-in-one tomcat for windows. This does however not mean, that my answer is wrong. The package will just contain a 64 bit JRE.
With a 64 bit system and JVM, you will not have to bother about memory limits for many many many years....