# apache tomcat permgem

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have modify the catalina.bat rem  JAVA_OPTS "-XX:MaxPermSize=5024M". But am still getting perm gem. am using grails but deployed to tomcat as a war file. Anything I did wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use SET not rem. REM can be ignored. They are just comments.

Answer (score 2):

In windows batch files, `rem` at the start of a line signifies a comment.  You will need to remove that for the line to have any effect on the batch file.  Try using jconsole to confirm that your settings are being applied.  If you are running out of memory after setting perm gen to 5Gb (which also [assumes you are running a 64 bit jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os)) you should check out one of the many other questions on this [starting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error).

Comment: Yeah, 5GiB for PermGen seems ... insanely high. OP likely has a memory leak.