# Java -Xmx command not giving me as much memory as I expected

Tags: java, memory, heap-size

I am running the following code using the java `-Xmx60g` command.

Each array should be around **8.5GB**, for a total of **17GB**. The machine has **64GB** total, with **63GB** "free." It prints `DONE DECLARING RIVER HANDS 1`, indiciating that it finished declaring the first array.

But I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
during the declaration of the second array. I am confused, because my understanding is that the `-Xmx60g` should allocate **60GB**, while the arrays only use **17GB**.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
long NUM_RIVER_HANDS = 2428287420L;
int half_river = (int)(NUM_RIVER_HANDS/2);
byte[][] river_hands_1 = new byte[half_river][7];
System.out.println("DONE DECLARING RIVER HANDS 1");
byte[][] river_hands_2 = new byte[(int)(NUM_RIVER_HANDS - half_river)][7];
System.out.println("DONE DECLARING RIVER HANDS 2");
```

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit JVM?  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os

Comment: Have you checked the resource monitor of you operating system? It could be that your assumption about the amount of memory things 'should' take is off.

Comment: What does Runtime.maxMemory() return? What does Runtime.freeMemory() return before and after you've allocated your first array? Have you tried running a profiler against your code?

Answer (score 4):

In the first allocation, you're creating 1214143710 arrays, each of which is 7 bytes *plus the object overhead*. If we assume a per-object overhead for an array of 16 bytes (which is reasonable, if not conservative) then that means *two thirds* of your space is being wasted. If we assume 24 bytes for each array in total, that's ~29GB just for the first allocation... and if there's more overhead than that, pushing it to 32 bytes for each array, for example, it's ~38GB, at which point it's not surprising that you can't do it twice :)

Just change the way you're using the arrays to make this *much* more efficient:

```
// Names changed to follow Java naming conventions
byte[][] riverHands1 = new byte[7][halfRiver];
byte[][] riverHands2 = new byte[7][(int)(NUM_RIVER_HANDS - halfRiver)];
```

You'll need to change how you *use* the arrays as well, but now you have a total of 14 `byte[]` objects, each of which is very large... but you'll have hardly any wasted memory due to object overheads.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon Skeet, that fixed it. Thanks also for informing me of the Java naming convention.

Comment: Whereas this is a great advice, I am finding it hard to explain what I am seeing. When I declare `long NUM_RIVER_HANDS = 1L << 33;` which is much bigger than `2428287420L`, the allocation goes fine and I see both the println's with default settings of heap memory on both Mac/Linux with 1.8.0_131. The moment I switch to  declaring with `2428287420L`, I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Does this involve some word boundary issues? Adding @apangin for some advice here.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade `(int)((1L << 33)/2)` is 0. Higher bits are truncated. Obviously, there is enough memory to create two zero-sized arrays.

Comment: Grr. Silly me. Thank you @apangin!