# Is there a upper limit to how much heap size JUnits can use

Tags: java, junit4

My Jenkins build is running out of memory because of JUnits. When I try to give it (the JUnits) more than 4GB it errors out. I am using Linux as my build machine.

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m
```

I am just wondering, is there a upper limit to how much heap size JUnits can use?

Comment: What OS are you using? This now highly depends on your OS.

Answer (score 3):

"For a 32-bit process model, the maximum virtual address size of the process is typically 4 GB, though some operating systems limit this to 2 GB or 3 GB. The maximum heap size is typically -Xmx3800m (1600m) for 2 GB limits), though the actual limitation is application dependent. For 64-bit process models, the maximum is essentially unlimited."

Found a pretty good answer here:

[Java maximum memory on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp)

Answer (score 2):

Memory is allocated to JVM not JUnit or any other class.
and there is limit on 32-bit system to assign max of 4Gb but if you requires more memory then move to 64 bit machine as there is no limit of max memory allocation .

Answer (score 1):

i would guess you are using a 32 bit jvm ..
check this post:

[Maximum Java heap size of a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os)

Answer (score 0):

It's not JUnit but JVM. 4GB heap is too much for 32-bit JVMs.