# Increasing java heap size general

Tags: java, size, heap-memory

I'm using a Windows 7 PC and i want to increase my java heap size but not for an application
So the command java -xmx4g e.g. is not possible.
I want to increase the java heap size in generel.
Is this somehow possible?
I appreciate every answer.

Sorry for my bad english

PS:  I'm using 64-bit JVM on a 64-bit Win 7 PC
     commands -java Xmx6G and set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024M -Xmx6144M does not work even when writing it in the startup.bat
I get the error in a program that consists of 10 same steps the first 4 are no problem but after the 4th i get the error.
Error: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Java heap space

Best regards,
Eros Kilinc

Comment: So you want to change the default value for the maximum heap size on your machine?

Comment: Related : [Maximum Java Heap Size of a 32 bit JVM on a 64 bit OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os)

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible on 64-bit JVM and 64-bit Windows, on 32-bit JVM / PC max heap size is about 1.2M

Comment: I am using 64-bit JVM and 64-bit Windows
I also tried the option with the system variable JAVA_OPTS but it's not working

Comment: I also have Win7-64 and Java 64-bit, java -Xmx4G test.Test1 works fine

Comment: yeah but like i said i dont want to have it on anything in particular like test.Test1 
i need it for everything so the command java -xmx6G does not work without something behind it

Comment: make sure it is -X and not -x in the first place