# Performance Issue in 32 bit Java web application

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, 32bit-64bit, heap-memory

Need advise on the performance issues faced on a java application.

I have an application on 32 bit JVM. The RAM is 16 GB. I have not been able to allocate more than 3 gb to heap size. The application has been coming to a halt once every week. I need to restart the application to bring it back. I am attaching the jstat result for one day and also the JVM parameters for that day.

I have tried multiple jvm parameters but this has not helped much. The next option looks to be a migration to 64 bit JVM. I request you to look at the data below and suggest options.

JVM parameters

> Xms3072m -Xmx3072m  -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
>   -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

JSTAT results

```
Mon Jan 26 00:19:39 EET 2015  Interval  60  seconds
Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
       286262.1 100.00   0.00  22.34  57.58  89.79  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286322.2 100.00   0.00  43.81  57.58  89.79  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286382.2 100.00   0.00  49.98  57.58  89.79  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286442.2 100.00   0.00  51.28  57.58  89.79  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286502.3 100.00   0.00  54.97  57.58  89.80  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286562.3 100.00   0.00  56.26  57.58  89.80  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286622.3 100.00   0.00  57.55  57.58  89.80  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286682.3 100.00   0.00  59.81  57.58  89.80  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286742.3 100.00   0.00  60.91  57.58  89.80  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286802.3 100.00   0.00  71.81  57.58  89.81  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286862.3 100.00   0.00  84.60  57.58  89.81  15554 3246.653  1051  701.262 3947.916
       286922.3   0.00  64.88  21.38  58.28  89.81  15555 3246.758  1051  701.262 3948.021
       286982.3   0.00  64.88  46.32  58.28  89.81  15555 3246.758  1051  701.262 3948.021
       287042.3   0.00  64.88  53.09  58.28  89.81  15555 3246.758  1051  701.262 3948.021
       287102.3   0.00  64.88  57.13  58.28  89.82  15555 3246.758  1051  701.262 3948.021
       287162.3   0.00  64.88  58.27  58.28  89.82  15555 3246.758  1051  701.262 3948.021
       287222.3   0.00  64.88  74.53  58.28  89.82  15555 3246.758  1051  701.262 3948.021
       287282.3   0.00  64.88  77.89  58.28  89.82  15555 3246.758  1051  701.262 3948.021
       287342.4   0.00  64.88  98.63  58.28  89.82  15555 3246.758  1051  701.262 3948.021
       287402.4  64.44   0.00   3.48  58.28  89.83  15556 3246.828  1051  701.262 3948.090


Mon Jan 26 23:42:24 EET 2015  Interval  60  seconds
Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
       370426.4   0.00  46.75  35.31  66.61  98.28  24171 5274.749  4433 3581.247 8855.996
       370486.4  53.09   0.00  82.74  66.42  98.28  24174 5275.000  4440 3589.427 8864.427
       370546.4   0.00  70.75  20.08  66.44  98.29  24177 5275.268  4447 3597.819 8873.088
       370606.5   0.00  87.29  95.62  66.48  98.30  24179 5275.997  4455 3604.747 8880.744
       370666.5  43.93   0.00  66.47  66.52  98.31  24182 5276.234  4463 3612.632 8888.866
       370726.5  73.27   0.00  13.07  66.67  98.31  24190 5278.474  4471 3620.204 8898.678
       370786.5   0.00  45.51  39.18  66.49  98.31  24193 5278.703  4479 3627.072 8905.775
       370846.5   0.00  28.57  69.10  66.08  98.32  24197 5279.345  4488 3632.354 8911.699
       370906.5   0.00  97.48  16.71  66.23  98.36  24203 5281.344  4496 3638.235 8919.579
       370966.5  87.66   0.00  54.15  66.37  98.37  24206 5281.611  4503 3645.747 8927.358
       371026.5   0.00  45.54  20.35  66.67  98.37  24209 5281.832  4511 3654.457 8936.289
       371086.5  72.28   0.00  28.90  66.67  98.37  24212 5282.108  4519 3661.300 8943.408
       371146.5  38.50   0.00  69.69  66.74  98.38  24216 5282.480  4527 3665.885 8948.365
       371206.5   0.00  44.33  41.07  66.48  98.39  24221 5283.158  4537 3672.664 8955.821
       371266.5   0.00  84.53  56.12  74.05  79.66  24229 5285.544  4544 3697.599 8983.143
       371326.5   0.00  60.22  83.81  66.12  79.67  24231 5285.983  4552 3706.708 8992.691
       371386.5   0.00  66.38  64.78  66.15  79.67  24235 5286.622  4560 3714.532 9001.154
       371446.5  27.16   0.00  83.74  70.22  79.68  24238 5287.051  4568 3725.204 9012.255
       371506.5   0.00 100.00  36.93  65.91  79.69  24241 5287.437  4576 3739.038 9026.475
       371566.5  53.98   0.00  36.05  67.48  79.70  24244 5288.096  4583 3749.627 9037.723
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum Java heap size of a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os)

Answer (score 0):

32-bit system can address 4GB of memory max.  Apparently you need to leave some memory for stack and JVM code.