# How to initialise JVM with larger maximum heap size using rJava

Tags: r, jvm, stanford-nlp, rjava

I am attempting to make use of the Stanford NLP tools (Java) in R, using the rJava package. When attempting to create a StanfordCoreNLP object I get the following error:

> Error in .jnew("edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP", props) : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

To resolve this, I have attempted to initialise the JVM with a larger maximum heap size, using variations of the following code:

```
.jinit(parameters=c("-Xms1g","-Xmx4g"))
```

When the maximum heap is set to 1GB using `-Xmx1g` the JVM loads but I continue to get the OutOfMemoryError. When the maximum heap size is set to 2 or 3 GB (`-Xmx2g` or `-Xmx3g`), R will stop responding. When set to 4GB or higher `-Xmx4g` I will get the following message:

> Error in .jinit(parameters = c("-Xms1g", "-Xmx4g"), force.init = TRUE) : Cannot create Java virtual machine (-6)

How do you successfully initialise the JVM using rJava to values larger than 1GB? I am using 32bit versions of Java (v8 u51) and R (v3.2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using 32bit versions of Java (v8 u51) and R (v3.2.0)

That's your problem right there. Switch to 64bit versions.

Comment: Okay, having read a bit more on the subject you are quite right (nice summary in this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os)). Frustratingly this will probably need another question, as I am using the 32bit version in the first place due to needing to access a database which only has 32bit ODBC drivers, where all the advice is "just use the 32bit version".

Comment: I'm in the same situation as @littlefeltfangs where I don't have a choice to use 64 bit and it's very frustrating not to have any solution within 32bit version