# What's is jvm max heap size (Xmx ) in GB?. I tried Xmx as 3GB

Tags: java

What's is jvm max heap size (Xmx ) in GB?. I tried Xmx as 3GB(3272 MB) and after that not allowed to define . It's failed to run .

Comment: it all depends on the RAM size, you can extend it max upto RAM size. But you also need to take into consideration all the other processes running on the machine and their RAM usage.

Comment: @piyushj thank you for reply. I'm using AIX6.0 and Java 1.5 . When I'm calling the Java program from shell script I set java Xmx as 3272m , its success and when I change more than this its fail to run

Comment: It also depends on the which JVM is installed 32 bit or 64 bit. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os