# Increasing RAM in cluster on remote server

Tags: java, r, h2o

I'm working on a remote server that has 196 GB of ram but when I run h2o.init(nthreads = -1) it says that I have 16 cores but only .96 GB of ram. I also receive the message saying that my Java is only 32 bit but h2o runs best on 64-bit. I have tried to use max_mem_size to increase the ram but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can utilize the power of the server in h2o? What do I need to do?

Comment: You need a 64 bit JVM for your operating system.  You won't get all available RAM, because of OS and other apps.  32 bit JVM won't allow more than 1.4-2GB of RAM.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os

Comment: I suggest you make sure your application fits into one NUMA region as it can perform very badly across multiple regions.