# JVM heap size not getting more than 1.6 GB for 64 bit JVM

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I have a 64 bit machine with 8 GB RAM , windows 7. I am using 64 bit JVM. Still I am unable to set Max heap size more than 1600 M. I have read almost all the answers related to this topic on stackoverflow.

Whenever I try to set max heap as -Xmx2048M I am getting:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine.

I have tried setting max heap size with `_JAVA_OPTION` system variable and also through:

Run -> Run Configuration -> Arguments path.

Both the times I am getting same error. RAM is almost free.

What is getting wrong?

Comment: try `-Xmx2048m` or `-Xmx2g` (lowercase m and g)

Comment: @mumpitz That doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Kayaman i remember once having the case where the jvm didn't want uppercase letters in the end of this argument. i don't remember if it was due to and old version or whatever, though.

Comment: Are you *really sure* that you are using a 64 bit JVM? `1600M` sounds pretty much like a typical limit of a 32 bit JVM. You can use the `-showversion` option to let the JVM print the relevant information without terminating.

Comment: How do you start your application?

Comment: Is your system 32 or 64 bit? check using keys: "WinFlag" + "Pause"

Comment: This will happen on Windows if you don't have enough free memory. In Task Manager how much memory does it say is free?

Comment: Below thread has similar discussion. Hope it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os

Answer (score 0):

***Server JVM Default Initial and Maximum Heap Sizes***

The default initial and maximum heap sizes work similarly on the server JVM as it does on the client JVM, except that the default values can go higher. On 32-bit JVMs, the default maximum heap size can be up to 1 GB if there is 4 GB or more of physical memory.

> On 64-bit JVMs, the default maximum heap size can be up to 32 GB if
>   there is 128 GB or more of physical memory.

You can always set a higher or lower initial and maximum heap by specifying those values directly; see the next section.

[Oracle official documentation on Java 8 min/max heap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#sthref30)