# Could not reserve enough space for object heap - Intellji 2018.1 with wildfly 9.0.2 - trying run web application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I am trying to run a web application project, but there is an error when executing

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

I attached an image for more detail

[Error details - intellji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr4FM.png)

I have been looking for the solution in different forums

the majority indicates
"Run the JVM with -XX: MaxHeapSize = 512m (or any big number) (or -Xmx512m for short)"

I have configured this in intellij, but the error persists 
-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
AND
-Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

[Config Xmx512m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpePp.png)

I am temporarily solving this problem by uninstalling wildfly (clean folder wildfly_902), reconfiguring jboss in Intellij and finally restarting the OS. But this I have to do every 4 hours

Feature:

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.4203.550, built on March 26, 2018

wildfly 9.0.2

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB

jdk 7

thx

Comment: How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: Is an Asus ROG with 32g of ram and I have enough available memory

Comment: Note that too big number of heap can give this error. As I see you are using 32bit JDK - it has [restrictions for the maximum available memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434901/2000323) for a single process. If you have 64bit OS it make sense to use 64bit JDK to run the server.

Comment: Excellent catch @Andrey!