# java- SDK version and Vm options

Tags: java

I am running a program on Intellij and my project SDK is currently set to version 1.7.

I tried to change the `VM options` to a `-Xmx10g` and
it throws an error claiming `Invalid Heap Space, JVM could not create`

So I tried changing the JDK to version 1.8 which is the latest and it doesn't throw any error at all and works fine.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: If you do not specify -Xms, heap starts at default initial value and grows to a maximum of 10GB. Do your PC have 10GB available memory?

Comment: Yea but i have to specify this much because otherwise it would throw out of memory GC overhead exceeded. What should i specify -Xms with?

Comment: You may try -Xms512m -Xmx4g first

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os

Comment: 4g is not enough, it runs halfway and throws OOM