# Getting error for increasing the Weblogic 10.3.6 heap size to 4 GB

Tags: heap-memory, weblogic-10.x

I am using Web logic 10.3.6 and Java 1.7.
My application is running out memory if keep heap space Xmx512m and Web logic is not able to acquire enough memory space when in am increasing to Xmx2048m.

First I have tried with `WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx512m`
For this my application is going out of memory at the server start up giving below error in console:

```
<Jan 26, 2019 4:42:55 PM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "InitializerServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myApp.war".
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jan 26, 2019 4:42:55 PM EST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application '_appsdir_myApp_war'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "InitializerServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "CUEPrepAndRating.war".
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)


the server doesn't start if I increase the heap space to set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx2048m

and give below error message:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Can you some one help how I can increase my web logic heap space enough(4GB) so that my application will run without the going out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not with a 32-bit JDK. See: [Maximum Java heap size of a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os) - you will not get higher than -Xmx1600m.

Comment: Thank you. I have got the 64 bit JDK and it resolved the issue.