# Max value of Xmx and Xms in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, memory-management, application-settings

My settings for these values in `eclipse.ini` are:

```
-Xms768M
-Xmx1024M
```

When setting them higher, Eclipse doesn't start anymore. Is there a way to increase these values without Eclipse crashing?

Comment: Since it depends on the operating system, see [Sizing the Java Heap](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg00014884d287-11c3fb28dae-7ff6_1001.html)

Comment: [This](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html) article should be helpful. It will show you which errors to avoid when setting the java heap size (the heap size shouldn't be greater than the physical memory in your PC for example).

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#generation_sizing

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The maximum values do not depend on Eclipse, it depends on your OS (and obviously on the physical memory available).

You may want to take a look at this question: [Max amount of memory per java process in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987219/max-amount-of-memory-per-java-process-in-windows/987576)

Comment: It also depends on the physical memory you have available.

Comment: There's a barrier for 32-bit Eclipse / JVM

Comment: Is it different from the limit for a 32-bit OS?

Answer (score 9):

I am guessing you are using a 32 bit eclipse with 32 bit JVM. It wont allow heapsize above what you have specified.

Using a 64-bit Eclipse with a 64-bit JVM helps you to start up eclipse with much larger memory. (I am starting with -Xms1024m -Xmx4000m)

Answer (score 8):

Why do you need -Xms768 (small heap must be at least 768...)?

That means any java process (search in eclipse) will start with 768m memory allocated, doesn't that? That is why your eclipse isn't able to start properly.

Try -Xms16 -Xmx2048m, for instance.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the following config for eclipse.ini:

```
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
```

Now eclipse performance is about 2 times faster then before.

You can also find a good help ref here: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html

Comment: The command line arguments did not overwrite what was defined in the .ini file. So editing the .ini file was the only solution for me.