# Flex builder4 - Compilation issue

Tags: flex4

I'm using FB4 and my project will take atleast 30 minutes to compile entire project since it has 20 modules.

Everyday i have to logoff my machine since our company policy.

My problem is :

Everyday i have to spend 30 minutes to compile my entire project. 
I have to spend another 30 minutes again to compile all modules in my project  if i accidently closed my project or closed my Flex builder IDE.

Do you have any suggestion to avoid flexbuilder to compile my project again if i closed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Java could probably use more memory to speed that up.

[How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)
[Max value of Xmx and Xms in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304312/max-value-of-xmx-and-xms-in-eclipse)

Is 'Build Automatically' selected?

Maybe how you link your projects will also impact performance.  Linking SWC instead of project references should improve time.