# Jmeter: How to implement upload a 1GB streaming file via PUT method and also aviod error out "out of memory"

Tags: file-upload, upload, jmeter

Recently, I took over a performance test. Its test scenario is upload and download 1GB stream file in size. Have used Jmeter HTTP Sampler (PUT Method) to send file, but always encounter 'OUT OF MEMORY' error. I tried to adjust to Jmeter HEAP size to fit in place,but it is not best way.

Have some guys come up with workaround (upload in segment) or solution for upload big file?

Comment: first question that pops in my mind is what machine are you using x86 or x64?

Comment: My jmeter running on x86 windows XP OS

Comment: I am asking because at some point I had something similar and when the java process went over 1GB of RAM, the application crashed.

Comment: OKay.Could you give me sort of clue or thought about this problem?

Comment: Coz the issue blocked me for some time and now the only thing is scratch my heads.....

Comment: Around 1.5 GB. Better information here:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987219/max-amount-of-memory-per-java-process-in-windows)

Comment: I heard rumors that people use 'http raw request' plugin to simulate huge uploads without memory overhead

Comment: I try to use 'http raw request' but always error out .Could you please give me a explicit PUT method example?