# Can't allocate a JVM heap of more than 1397mb

Tags: java, jvm, command-line-arguments, jvm-arguments

If I try to run Java with more than 1397mb using -Xmx1397m command line parameter it fails to initialize. Why is this?

I.E.:

- "`java path\java.exe" -Xmx1397m`  -> works
- `java path\java.exe" -Xmx1398m` ->crashes

The machine almost 100GB of unused ram and I'm running 32bit java

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987219/max-amount-of-memory-per-java-process-in-windows/987576#987576). You probably should consider moving to 64-bit JVM.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue with 32bit java on Windows that you can't get the expected 3 GB of heap due to address space fragmentation issues. The HotSpot JVM needs a *contiguous* address block for its heap, and some shared DLLs that are permanently mapped into user space are fragmenting the space.