# JDeveloper: Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: jdeveloper

Hi i am encountering the following error when deploying an project from my jdeveloper studio.

```
 [scac] Error occurred during initialization of VM
 [scac] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Can anyone advise on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you have enough free RAM on your computer:

go to `jdev.conf` file (`~/Oracle/middleware/jdeveloper/jdev/bin`) and add more memory to the file

I haven't checked but you could add:

```
AddVMOption  -XX:MaxHeapSize=512m
```

or whatever you want

more help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: Changing this setting I'm unable to start JDeveloper. Instead changing ant-sca-compile.xml amount of memory works:

       <jvmarg value="-Xmx700m"/>

Answer (score 1):

See in \jdeveloper\bin\ant-sca-compile.xml

Change Xmx value of line specified in JDe. Your system can't reserve enought memory.

Comment: Ty, I've changed my settings in the ant-sca-compile.xml

             <jvmarg value="-Xmx700m"/>

Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the value -Xmx on \jdeveloper\bin\ant-sca-compile.xml worked for me:

```
<target name="scac" description="Compile and validate a composite">
  <scac input="${scac.input}" outXml="${scac.output}" error="${scac.error}" appHome="${scac.application.home}" failonerror="true" displayLevel="${scac.displayLevel}">
    <jvmarg value="-Xms128m"/>
    #<jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx700m"/>
    <jvmarg value="-XX:PermSize=32m"/>
    <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"/>
    <!-- jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"/ -->
  </scac>
</target>
```

If you change jdev.conf you may experience the error:

> Unable to create instance of the Virtual Java Machine Located at Path:
>   C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll