# JDeveloper Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I have run into an issue with JDeveloper when I am trying to build a composite to deploy for Sugar.  I am running JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 running on Window 7 with 16GB of RAM and when I try to build the composite I see the following message

```
Buildfile: C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\bin\ant-sca-compile.xml

scac:
     [scac] Validating composite "C:\JDevProjects\NotificationService\NotificationServiceProject\composite.xml"
     [scac] Error occurred during initialization of VM
     [scac] Could not reserve enough space for object heap

BUILD FAILED
C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\bin\ant-sca-compile.xml:278: Java returned: 1 Check log file : C:\JDevProjects\NotificationService\NotificationServiceProject\SCA-INF\classes\scac.log for errors

Total time: 1 second
```

Searching around I have gotten numerous recommendations of changes to the ide.conf and jdev.conf.
[JDeveloper: Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045697/jdeveloper-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Currently I have the jdev.conf set at

```
AddVMOption -Xmx512M
AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

and in the ide.conf I have

```
AddVMOption -Xms256M
AddVMOption -Xmx512M
```

I have also tried changing the `ant-sca-compile.xml`

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2421702

and adding the environment variable `EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES`.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2133213

Nothing has been fruitful.

I compiled this fine a few days ago and now I can't get it to work.  Occasionally before I would get this and I could remedy this by closing a few other applications, now that doesn't work any more.

Comment: Hate to ask a dumb question, but did you try restarting your computer? How much RAM does the Activity Monitor app show is available?

Comment: 32 or 64 bit JVM?  32 bit JVMs require contiguous address space and whether or not that is available is entirely dependent on what dlls are loaded and "where" they are loaded in memory, which then depends on what applications are running.  Before you answer, make sure you check both the JVM running jdeveloper *and* what jvm is being used by whatever spawned process is triggering the error (I imagine they can be different)

Comment: @MattBall I did try restarting my computer numerous times.  According to the activity monitor I have 10GB Available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following changes

Edit the ant-sca-compile.xml to have the following values :

```
<jvmarg value="-Xms512m"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
```

The jdev.conf file config should be as follows:

```
AddVMOption –Xmx1280M
AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
AddVMOption -XX:MaxHeapSize=512M
```

And the composite now builds.

Thanks,

Tom