# Java Could not reserve enough space for object heap error

Tags: java, jvm, minecraft

I have Java7 running on 32-bit Windows and 4 GB RAM, but:

```
java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar Minecraft.jar 
java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar Minecraft.jar 
java -Xmx2G -Xms2G -jar Minecraft.jar
```

...still does not work. Error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>       Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>       Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>       Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

`java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar Minecraft.jar` is working. Why?

Comment: This is explained by this Oracle Java FAQ - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit

Comment: Some more detailed answers can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp

Comment: if you install 64 bit version of java, it will directly work.

Answer (score 66):

Go to `Start` → `Control Panel` → `System` → `Advanced system settings` → `advanced(tab)` → `Environment Variables` → `System Variables` → `New`:

```
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: Nice way to avoid configuring so much tools. Thanks. I tried to configure the flag on the VM instance, but for sure i did it wrong. Using system variable is by far better and just one time. Thank you.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I was building in IntelliJ and had to restart the program though

Answer (score 10):

If you go thru [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg00014884d287-11c3fb28dae-7ff6_1001.html) IBM link on java, it says that on 32 bit windows the recommended heap size is 1.5 GB and the Maximum heap size is 1.8 GB. So your jvm does not gets initialized for `-Xmx2G` and above.

Also if you go thru [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497757/1291122) SO answer, clearly the DLL bindings are an issue for memory reservation changing which is no trivial task. Hence what may be recommended is that you go for 64-bit Windows and a 64-bit JVM. while it will chew up more RAM, you will have much more contiguous virtual address space.

Comment: java -Xmx1240m -Xms1240m -jar Minecraft.jar

still does not work.

Comment: @KemalTunca try java -Xmx1240m -jar Minecraft.jar

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem. I solved it with downloading 64x of the Java. Here is the link: http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=87443

Comment: Setting less memory did not work at all for me, but this worked immediately.

Answer (score 9):

This was occuring for me and it is such an easy fix.

1. you have to make sure that you have the correct java for your system such as 32bit or 64bit.
2. if you have installed the correct software and it still occurs than goto

   `control panel` → `system` → `advanced system settings` for Windows 8 or

   `control panel` → `system and security` → `system` → `advanced system settings` for Windows 10.
3. you must goto the {advanced tab} and then click on {Environment Variables}.
4. you will click on {New} under the `<system variables>`
5. you will create a new variable. Variable name: `_JAVA_OPTIONS`  Variable Value: `-Xmx512M`

At least that is what worked for me.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I was building in IntelliJ and had to restart the program though.

Answer (score 3):

to make sure it runs the 64 bit version of java have it like this:

"c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx1536M -Xms1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-universal.jar

take a look at what jre version you have installed just in case.. x64 should be in program files while x32 resides in Program Files (x86)

Comment: You missed out the `-d64` operator

Answer (score 2):

4gb RAM doesn't mean you can use it all for java process. Lots of RAM is needed for system processes.
Dont go above 2GB or it will be trouble some.

Before starting jvm just check how much RAM is available and then set memory accordingly.

Comment: java -Xmx1240m -Xms1240m -jar Minecraft.jar still does not work.

Comment: Can you check in Task manager before starting jvm, how much memory is available ?

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me (yes I was having the same problem) 
were is says something like `java -Xmx3G -Xms3G` put `java -Xmx1024M`
so the run.bat should look like 
`java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o false
PAUSE`

Answer (score 1):

Double click Liferay CE Server -> add -XX:MaxHeapSize=512m to Memory args -> Start server!
Enjoy...

It's work for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old subject. But those using a stack, like Bitnami WildFly 13, should know that the stack installation has its own Java engine in `\Bitnami\wildfly-13.0.0-1\java`.
On Windows, the installation takes the stack Java own engine for default configurations and it starts Java with option -client, not -server, even though there is/are other Java engines installed in the system. You need to modify `standalone.conf.bat` to specify explicitly your Java path and add -server option along with the desired memory allocation.
Example:

```
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311”
set "JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xms2048M -Xmx4096M"
:JAVA_OPTS_SET
rem set "JAVA_HOME=C:\opt\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\java"
```

I hope this helps.