# setting the heap size of a 32 bit JVM on a 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, websphere-8, rad

I have a 64 bit Windows 7 machine with a 32 bit JVM. I have used the following commands to check whether my JVM is 32-bit or 64-bit

```
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

The application I'm working on requires more heap space than the default 256 MB.So I have set the initialHeapSize=256 MB and maximumHeapSize=1490 MB in my Websphere Application Server 8.0.However after setting these properties in admin console,I'm not able to start the application server .It says "Error occured during start-up". If i set the maximumHeapSize=1230 MB, then the application server starts.But I have a requirement where i need the heap size to be increased upto 1900 MB. I'm completely out of options. Please help !!

Thanks

Comment: there is any option from `java -X` that helps ? type it in your console .

Comment: sorry .. I dint get wat you are trying to say

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20264362/2485710

Comment: So u suggest that i run this command java -Xmx2048m -Xms256m and the JVM will be able to utilise upto 2048 MB?? Dont i need to set in the application server?? .But i got an error saying could not reserve enough space for the object heap

Comment: I you are dealing with a bottleneck that depends on the JVM settings usually those command line options are enough to fix the problem, just try it.

Comment: but it gave me an error saying 'could not reserve enough space for the object heap'

Comment: I noticed that your requirements are exceeding the limits of a 32 bit JVM http://stackoverflow.com/a/18040492/2485710

Comment: We have an option to set the initial and maximum heap size in Websphere application server. How does this differ from the Xmx command??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47515/discussion-between-gogo-and-user2485710)

Comment: this options are provided by the "standard" jvm from Sun/Oracle and affects anything runs under the JVM itself, but this options and are not granted to be there because there are other vendors that are free to implement or not this command line options . I don't have time for chat right now, but in nutshell if this options are available to you I would prefer this over any software settings.

Comment: Ok.. I will give it a try and will see. Thanks. But have i used the right approach to find out if the JVM is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell what error you are seeing in WAS logs probably in native_stderr.log or native_stdout.log file when the value set to "1490mb" ?

Are you specifying those values under "Application servers > server_name > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine" section ?

-vt
Note: These opinions are my own

Comment: Yes. I am setting the values under Java Virtual Machine.But i need to set the Heap size to around 1900 MB. Is it possible?