# Meteor while running on android device gives this error

Tags: android, meteor, meteor-cordova

Suddenly out of no where I am seeing this issue with starting app on device.
 I have been struggling for long with no luck while trying to start meteor on android device.

I use meteor run android-device to run on device btw!

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:
   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed:
   C:\Users\ally\Documents\GitHub\Portal-Meteor\portalMeteor\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\cordova\run
   --device --device
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
   * What went wrong:
   Unable to start the daemon process.
   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at
   http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
   Please read the following process output to find out more:
   -----------------------
   Error occurred during initialization of VM
   Could not reserve enough space for object heap
   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
   * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
   Error code 1 for command: cmd with args:
   /s,/c,"C:\Users\ally\Documents\GitHub\Portal-Meteor\portalMeteor\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\gradle
w
   cdvBuildDebug -b
   C:\Users\ally\Documents\GitHub\Portal-Meteor\portalMeteor\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\build.gradle
   -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" undefined
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (C:\tools\utils\processes.js:151:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

C:\Users\ally\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\nod
e_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:116
      throw error;
            ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

Comment: Seems like the JVM does not have enough RAM. Take a look at [this question]. Either your PC does not have enough free RAM, your program takes too much (less likely) or you should increase the amount of RAM available to JVM (most likely).

Comment: I cannot see the question you are referring to, also my PC has 16 gb of ram and can you please suggest some references to increase ram for JVM?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18040361/268093).

Answer (score 0):

removing and re-installing android studio worked :)