# Katalon CLI Command Remote Execution Error

Tags: java, katalon-studio, remotecommand, winrs

I am trying to run the CLI command generated by Katalon Remotely. But I am getting an error for it.

Command -

> winrs -r: D:\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.4.2\katalon
>   -noSplash  -runMode=console -projectPath="D:\Automation\QaAutomation.prj" -statusDelay=5 -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/Collection/Members" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Chrome"

Error -

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Uploading report to Katalon Analytics...
System is unable to send report to Katalon Analytics. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.kms.katalon.integration.analytics.report.AnalyticsReportIntegration.uploadTestSuiteResult(AnalyticsReport
Integration.java:40)
        at com.kms.katalon.execution.launcher.ReportableLauncher.uploadReportToIntegratingProduct(ReportableLauncher.jav
a:258)
        at com.kms.katalon.execution.launcher.ReportableLauncher.preExecutionComplete(ReportableLauncher.java:78)
        at com.kms.katalon.execution.launcher.ProcessLauncher.onWatchdogComplete(ProcessLauncher.java:171)
        at com.kms.katalon.execution.launcher.LaunchWatchdog.notifyProcessTerminated(LaunchWatchdog.java:135)
        at com.kms.katalon.execution.launcher.LaunchWatchdog.run(LaunchWatchdog.java:65)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Request sent successfully.
```

Please help me with this?

Or can someone suggest me some alternative to executing the CLI command from a different system?

My goal is to setup a CI system like Jenkins or Bamboo in PC1 and the scripts should run in PC2 when I run the build in PC1

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have an issue with your java installation.

You need to increase the memory of your java VM with the option -Xmx512M

Refer to this question. It will give you more help.
[Java Could not reserve enough space for object heap error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040361/java-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-error/24406013#24406013)

As of your second question, you can do it several ways. The most secure way is to make jenkins ssh session to new machine and run the command on that logged session (or use a slave to do the job). Remember that you need to have both katalon studio/target browsers installed and your test code on the remote machine.