# Unable to start Weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, weblogic

I am using Windows 8 Pro 64 bit, Java 1.6 64 bit. I am trying to start Weblogic with following memory args (setDomainEnv.cmd):

> set USER_MEM_ARGS=-Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

But i'm getting an error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Those mermory args are required to deploy the app, so i can't lower it (physical mermory installed - 8 GB).

Comment: looks like java32 bit is getting executed. Check the path and output of java -version

Comment: If you are using java 32 bit version, 32-bit version of Java requires a contiguous block of memory.As Jayan suggested use java 64 bit version and see if you are still landing in issue. Have a look at this url for more details http://www.laurencegellert.com/2011/11/java-startup-memory-issue-solved/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined with -Xmx512M use -d64 to make sure you're running 64-bit VM. On a 64-bit machine I thought for sure I was running 64-bit virtual machine, but no. After installing 64-bit Java the -d64 option works and -Xmx allows much larger memory sizes.

java -d64 -Xmx512M mypackage.Test

Please see the below link for more solutions...

[Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: My fault actually. I was using 32 bit java actually.

Answer (score 0):

I am running weblogic 81. I had min=1024 and max =1024m with 4gb or RAM. 64bit processor and 32 bit java. I tried to increase the min/max value, it did not work. So, I changed the min/max to 512m and 1024m respectively. Thn it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

When i installed for first time, the SOA environment developed mode, needed to do that:set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% set DEFAULT_MEM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx768m set    PORT_MEM_ARGS=-Xms768m -Xmx1536m  But over time, it shows me the same error and tube to make the following change: set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% set DEFAULT_MEM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m set PORT_MEM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m But I'm still not sure why this happens.