# GWT Compiler: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, gwt, compiler-construction, jvm

If anyone could help me with this problem.

I was running the application on Windows 64 bits e it was working fine, but I changed the computer and now it's running on 32 bits.

This error could be about this or it is some configuration?

EDIT: Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Thanks

Comment: In addition, it's intellij 12, gwt 2.5 and jdk 7

Comment: There are many possible reasons for something like that.  We need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your IntelliJ's available memory space is not large enough to allocate 1024 to your process. Try reducing the JVM size for your process or increase the IntelliJ JVM memory size

EDIT:
I just learned that the process will not run inside the memory space of the IntelliJ JVM, albeit its own. Also a quick search on the www lead me to understand that the max size of the heap that can be allocated is limited to around 4 GB on a 32bit machine subject to the availability of enough contiguous memory... generally gets limited to 1.2 GB. That might be the problem in your case

Comment: I have already tried this.
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: Oh no, I am saying it might only work with a smaller -Xmx value for the JVM on the compiler process.

Comment: I tried to put s smaller value, and also didn't work...

check my idea's file:

-Xms64m
-Xmx128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCOdeCacheFlushing
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: The issue is not with your IntelliJ Idea JVM config. It is with the GWT compiler JVM arguments. If you are launching compiler through intelliJ's run configuration dialog, that is where the change needs to go. Else if there is a build script, the JVM args need to be modified on that script.

Comment: Thanks man, I solved my problem, it wasn't the configuration in the idea as you said, I was the gwt compiler, that was configured to 2048. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your -Xmx setting on 64bit is larger the one supported by 32bit. You could provide more details about the problem too.

Comment: it is the same of the older project, -Xmx1024m. What information do you need?

Comment: @user3215190 the stacktrace that you get would help.

Comment: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Comment: @Cesar90 try running it with : -Xmx 512m. Read this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap