# exoPlatform error while installing in command prompt

Tags: java, cmd, jvm, portal, intranet

I tried to install and use eXoPlatform on my (windows) computer, but when I try to install it using the command prompt (cmd) an error occurs.

> Error occurred during initialization of VM, could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap. Error : could not create the JAVA VIRTUAL
>   MACHINE. Error : A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Post the error so we can help you

Comment: Error occurred during initialization of VM, could not reserve enough space for object heap. Error : could not  create the JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE. Error : A fatal  exception has occurred. Program will exit.  P.S. I can not upload picture of error due to my reputation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not reserve enough space for object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)