# Processing and heap size

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to run the [first example](http://www.creativeapplications.net/processing/augmented-reality-with-processing-tutorial-processing/) of augmented reality in Processing. Upon hitting the run button I get the following message:

```
[0] "Error occurred during initialization of VM"
[1] "Could not reserve enough space for object heap"
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The sketch is run on a computer with 8GB of RAM, Processing (x86) and I've increased the maximum available memmory to 2048MB in the preferences, but it still doesn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap

Comment: If you are using Windows XP or 32-bit JVM on windows, the largest continuous memory available will be between 1.2 and 1.5 GB.  If you use a 64-bit JVM you won't have this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVM needs contiguous memory space to initialize. Hence, it is not able to reserve the amount of memory you specified. See if it works by reducing the heap space

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think about reducing it. Reducing RAM to 512MB did the trick.