# Heap space Exception

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I have 16GB RAM and 64bit windows operating system.I want to run an web application I got heap space exception  if i change VM arguments to `-Xms3512m -Xmx3512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=32m` I got exception as

```
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

but I have another system with same configuration but that system accept this VM Arguments. please give me solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not reserve enough space for object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit JVM?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the heap size with: `XX:MaxHeapSize=??m`

Comment: when i put XX:MaxHeapSize=??m i got this excepiton "Unrecognized VM option 'MaxHeapSize=??m'"
do i need to replace XX:maxpermsize with xx:maxheapsize=??m

Comment: you need to put the amount you want to allocate where the `??` are, i.e.: `XX:MaxHeapSize=256m`

Answer (score 0):

Heap allocation done at the JVM initialization. It look for contiguous memory space of size -Xmx. If it could not find the continuous space of Xmx size then JVM failed during initialization  Please add the argument -verbose:init  and check the console output to identify which stage it failed on initialization.