# ionic error - Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB

Tags: object, ionic-framework, heap-memory

[I am getting error while building the android apk in ionic. It says "Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap. I tried various option but didnt work out. Please Help"][1]

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Oka.jpg">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Gradle error "Could not reserve enough space for object heap" constantly in Intellij IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143740/getting-gradle-error-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-constantly)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. For me the solution provided by Roman Ashikhmin worked but I found that you also need following Environment Variable too,

`GRADLE_OPTS` : `-Xmx2048M`

along with the

`_JAVA_OPTIONS` : `-Xmx1024M`

Note: For `_JAVA_OPTIONS` I tried going over 1024M to 2048M or even 4096M but those options don't work. You can do 512M & or 1024M. For `GRADLE_OPTS` gogin over 2048M didn't work either.

I'm on:

```
Java 32bit jdk-8u141
```

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a Windows Environment Variable named `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with value `-Xmx512M`.

It helped me to resolve the same issue.