# Cordova Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am new to cordova and am trying to create an android HelloWold project.

When I use `cordova platforms add android`, it throws some exception:

```
D:\CordovaSpace\helloWorld>cordova platforms add android
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.example.helloworld
        Name: HelloWorld
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-24
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Java_Android_SDK\android_sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\CordovaSpace\helloWorld\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: shall we send you some more RAM?

Comment: you lack of 2 GB ram I think

Comment: So what should I do ? (Please forgive me that I can not speak English very well)

Comment: buy more RAM? How much do you have at the moment?

Comment: I check my Computer Ram hava   about 3.84 G

Comment: looks like it is not enough

Comment: @ScaryWombat So easy to be sarcastic! My system has 9Gb of free memory and I still get the same problem.

Comment: @C-F Yes, sorry humour does not scale well on the internet.

Answer (score 111):

Try again after increasing your Java VM(?) memory size.

Here is how to fix it on a Windows platform:

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced(tab) -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> New:
Variable name: `_JAVA_OPTIONS`
Variable value: `-Xmx512M`

Don't ignore the score and underscore characters.

Comment: Add a local or user environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS works just as well.

Comment: [source](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-resolved.88119/) ?

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, but after restarting the `cli`.

Comment: Works like charm!

Comment: It Works, Thank you

Comment: This works for me, but after that, I can't open eclipse anymore.

Comment: @Roman IntelliJ also inherits from these settings. It even ignores its own settings to use this one. Dealbreaker for me.

Answer (score 13):

I had the exact same problem. I switched to use 64-bit JDK as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589518/2627218) and it worked fine. I was using Ionic 3.5.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 8):

this worked for my ionic app.

Change line on

```
// to allow dex in process
'org.gradle.jvmargs': '-Xmx1024m',
```

from

```
// to allow dex in process
'org.gradle.jvmargs': '-Xmx2048m',
```

in your

```
<app path>\platforms\android\cordova\lib\config
```

thanks

Comment: Thanks, your answer solved my problem, I was stuck for 3 days. I applied many different things. but ignoring your answer as score is less. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

```
args.push('-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m') 
into 
args.push('-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m');
```

on the following location files.

1. project-folder\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js
2. project-folder\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\StudioBuilder.js

Answer (score 3):

Go to : \platforms\android\cordova\lib\config\GradlePropertiesParser.js

```
constructor (platformDir) {
        this._defaults = {
            // 10 seconds -> 6 seconds
            'org.gradle.daemon': 'true',

            // to allow dex in process
            'org.gradle.jvmargs': '-Xmx2048m',

            // allow NDK to be used - required by Gradle 1.5 plugin
            'android.useDeprecatedNdk': 'true'

            // Shaves another 100ms, but produces a "try at own risk" warning. Not worth it (yet):
            // 'org.gradle.parallel': 'true'
        };
```

And change the `'org.gradle.jvmargs': '-Xmx2048m',` to `'org.gradle.jvmargs': '-Xmx1024m',`

Answer (score 2):

```
args.push('-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m') 
 to  
args.push('-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m');
```

on the following location files.

1. project-folder\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\builders.js
2. project-folder\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js
3. project-folder\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\StudioBuilder.js

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced(tab) -> Environment Variables -> System Variables`

Add/change `JAVA_HOME` value 
    `from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_192
    to         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192`

That is, change from `Program Files (x86)` path to `Program Files` path.

Comment: And install the 64bit version if you don't have it.

Comment: The above comment solved my issue. Java_Home was pointing to a 32 bit version.

Comment: Happy to know it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem.

Anyway, here is how to fix it:
Go to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced(tab)->Environment Variables->System Variables->New:
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS

## Variable value: -Xmx512M

if 512 not work then change it to.

## Variable value: -Xmx1024M

And also change the path.

Variable name: Path

## Variable value: ;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;F:\JDK\bin;

Change this to your appropriate path.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the environment variable at system level as in the @kemal's solution will set the memory size for all the JVM applications in the system, which is not a what most would want to do.

Instead, set the heap size in your cordova gradlebuilder property file.

```
args.push('-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m');
```

Comment: Do you mean `project/platforms/android/build.gradle`?