# Ionic Project issue Cordova Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Tags: ionic-framework

**I am facing some issues while run my ionic project to the device.** Please Help me resolve the issue.

C:\MobileProjects\Angular\sample-app>ionic cordova run android
......
[13:44:18]  lint started ...
[13:44:18]  build dev finished in 46.35 s

> cordova run android
>   [13:44:50]  lint finished in 32.50 s
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Technotricks\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre``
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for de
>   tails

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
  3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
  3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).

D:\MobileProjects\Angular\sample-app>

Comment: so did you try to run with `--stacktrace` to see where the failure occurs? somewhere you're trying to (directly or indirectly) create a huge object of 2GB

Comment: This is something about your environment variables. Try changing your `JAVA_HOME` variable to resolve it.

Comment: Look here [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216921/cordova-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-2097152kb-object-heap)

Comment: look the [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216921/cordova-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-2097152kb-object-heap)

Answer (score 0):

Try again after increasing your Java VM(?) memory size.

Here is how to fix it on a Windows platform:

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced(tab) -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> New:
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M

Don't ignore the score and underscore characters.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216921/cordova-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-2097152kb-object-heap)