# Cant build ionic app in ionic version 2.2.3

Tags: android, gradle, ionic2, jvm, daemon

Im new to Ionic 2 and I cant build my app, Im using Ionic Version 2.2.3. I already tried different solutions like adding some Environmental Variables but I still cant build. Hope you can help me, thanks in advance. Here is the error in cmd:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`enter code here`

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:

Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM


Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

Comment: is 2.2.3 your `ionic-angular` version? or cli? and what command did you use to build?

Comment: its my CLI v2.2.3 and i use "ionic build android" command to build.

Comment: what is the output for `cordova requirements`

Comment: Its an error sir.  "Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project."

Comment: run the command in your project folder

Comment: It shows: Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Please install Android target: "android-25".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\And
roid\android-sdk\tools\android.bat"
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-25
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
Gradle: installed
Error: Some of requirements check failed

Comment: Ah.. its a heap problem..sry.. check https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232909/4826457

Comment: okay sir, thank you very much. It was a huge help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216921/cordova-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-2097152kb-object-heap)

Comment: thank you but still didn't work for me, I have no idea how to resolve this. I'm desperately need a solution.