# Ionic 3 Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to deploy my freshly created Ionic 3 app (I am using 64-bit Windows 10) on my mobile but it is throwing error after running `ionic cordova run android --device`:

```
> cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=D:\android-sdk\tools\bin
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).
```

I have installed Android studio. 
I have added a system variable _ JAVA_OPTIONS with value -Xmx512M
I have also added a system variable GRADLE_OPTS with value -Xmx2048M

Otherwise I have:

```
ANDROID_HOME=D:\android-sdk\tools\bin
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
```

Why is this error still occurring?

Comment: You are building your app by your mobile?

Comment: I want to install the app on my mobile, I am running these commands from command prompt

Comment: Have you tried to increase the memory for the JVM as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232909/5730444)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix it on a Windows platform:

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced(tab) -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> New: 
Variable name: `_JAVA_OPTIONS` 
Variable value: `-Xmx512M`

Don't ignore the score and underscore characters.