# ionic cordova build android - daemon build error, where to find APK?

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm dying trying to figure this out!

Essentially, I've finished up an Ionic app and am ready to publish it to the Google Play Store. The problem is that I'm having trouble following the directions posted on the Ionic Framework website.

So far, I've created an 'android' folder under 'platforms'.

Error thrown:

> Android Studio project detected
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\fromf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_191
>   studio
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Subproject Path: app
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Unable to start the daemon process.
>     This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>     For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>     Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
>   ### Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
>
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>     (node:43720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

My various attempts:

1. Firstly, that I cannot seem to find the 'build' folder referenced at 'platforms/android/build/outputs/apk'. It simply does not exist.
2. Having recognised that I'm lacking the 'build' folder, I attempted to change the environment variables according to this website: http://www.tiagoporto.com/blog/environment-setting-tutorial-ionic-android-on-windows/. This did not work.
3. I followed the directions given on various SoF Q&As, and manually downloaded the needed gradle, called "gradle-2.2.1-all.zip". Still did not work.

I am at my wits ends. Please please please help!

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232909/8850397

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda I tried that already.