# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. ‘Error occurred during initialization of VM’ ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I’m very new to the Ionic framework

```
npm install -g cordova

npm install -g ionic

ionic start test blank

cd test

ionic platform add android
```

and this is my ionic info :

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.8 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v13.1.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.12.1
   OS                : Windows 7
```

When I use ’ >ionic build android ’
and boom i get an error.

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=FR -Duser.language=fr -Duser.variant -cp C:\Program Files\gradle-6.0.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.0.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.0.1
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
C:\Program Files\gradle-6.0.1\bin\gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**please i was spended a lot of time to trying to solve the problem but i can’t solved
if any one know to solve the problem please tell me**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i seloved by Uninstall jdk 8.191 and then install jdk 8.231

Answer (score 0):

According to **sky007**

this
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cordova-build-android-fails/102638/2

```
line:args.push(’-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m’);
```

in Your Project file where

```
platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js
```

also in this thread (Ionic Framework forum)

**Sujan12**

**Community Moderator (not Ionic Team)**

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-when-i-build-my-apk-file/138153/5

try to increase **RAM**

if none of helps check out this

[Cordova Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216921/cordova-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-2097152kb-object-heap)

Comment: i dont have file GradleBuilder.js

Comment: l have builders.js and ProjectBuilder.js in my platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\