# Below error occur when run this command "ionic cordova run android"

Tags: ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVK75.png)
Why does this error occur in ionic while running the command ionic Cordova run Android " [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess Cordova.Cordova.cmd build Android exited with exit code 1."?

Comment: it occurs due to various reasons can you post error pic completely?

Comment: I have added an image description.

Comment: this is your problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216921/cordova-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-2097152kb-object-heap