# Cordova failed to build APK for android

Tags: android, cordova, java-8, apk

I want to build my project **APK** using **Cordova**.

Previously, when I built the **APK** there was an error that my **JDK** didn't support, **Cordova** needed **JDK 1.8** while I was using **JDK 11**.

The **JDK** error disappeared but now another error appears like this:

[image]

Comment: Error says that, you do not have enough space. So, throwing heap size related error, please increase RAM space and try again.

Comment: and how i do that?

Comment: Check this it will help you: [Cordova Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232909/13632102)

Answer (score 0):

it solved, thaks to Harsh Patel.

This is the link to solved the problem [Cordova Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232909/13632102)