# Unable to create Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I'm just trying to create my first android studio project with a blank activity but i get this error while trying :
[image]

I found on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap) that a possible solution is to "

Run the JVM with -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m (or any big number), and possibly -Xmx512m" but I don't know how to do that ? I use windows 7

Comment: Search for key phrases in the error message. There is a wealth of information out there on this subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not reserve enough space for object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: I have set the path to the JDK correctly so I don't understand why i get this error

Comment: look at the accepted answer in the duplicate i pasted. if not you can just search for *Could not reserve enough space for object heap*. Searching google for the error message usually helps.

Comment: Ok how can I "

Run the JVM with -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m (or any big number), and possibly -Xmx512m
" ? I use windows 7

Comment: Gradle is fussy. Ensure you have set %java_home% and not just %path%