# How to Install Bi Server in Pentaho?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, pentaho

While installing  Pentaho Bi Server

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not reserve enough space for object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: Hi. This is a Java error, and it's a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap You might be running out of memory, or not setting the Heap large enough.