# Java heap memory in Web logic server

Tags: weblogic

I have installed , SOA(11g Version), when i am starting weblogic server, i am getting below error
"Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine."

My system having 8GB RAM, and using java 1.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not reserve enough space for object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: I suppose your admin server is already up and running and you have node manger associated to the machine which has been enrolled successfully to this domain. In this case, go to your servers-->soa-server-->server start parameters. Under arguments section, have below values defined and try starting your managed server.
            
            -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m

you would need to similar tuning on perm size as well.