# Could not reserve heap space

Tags: java

I am using soap ui 5.0.0 open source. I am running soapui testcases through ant to get the Junit report

build.xml:

```
<project basedir="." default="testreport" name="FCMRestAPIAutomation">
<target name="SoapUI">  
    <exec dir="." executable="C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\testrunner.bat">
    <arg line="-r -j -o -f 'C:\Users\sn3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder' -sFirstLoginTest 'C:\Users\sn3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\FCM Project.xml'"></arg>
</exec>
</target>
<target name="testreport" depends="SoapUI">
<junitreport todir="C:\Users\sn3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\API">
 <fileset dir="C:\Users\sn3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\API">
<include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
</fileset>
<report format="frames" todir="C:\Users\sn3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\reports\html">
 </report>
 </junitreport>
 </target>
</project>
```

Error in the command prompt:

```
SoapUI:
     [exec] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
     [exec] Error occurred during initialization of VMError: A fatal exception h
as occurred. Program will exit.
     [exec]
     [exec] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
     [exec] Result: 1

testreport:
[junitreport] Processing C:\Users\sn3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\API\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\sn3020722\AppData\Local\Temp\null913190532
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/D:/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8
.3.v201301120609/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit
/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 312ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Users\sn20722\AppData\Local\Temp\null913190532
```

I have added the following in the system environment variables.

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048MB
```

But still i am facing other issue that Soapui itself is not opened with the allotted space.. Any suggestion to workout the space issue..?

Comment: This means the vm can't allocate enough memory, ergo you do not have enough free physical memory (check top/task manager). Also: The _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable will be picked up by any java process, I do not recommend to use those.

Comment: i do have enough physical memoery space,,

Comment: how you run your tests? Please show full command, with options.

Comment: i will go in to the path where my build.xml is there in command prompt and give ant so that it will look the build.xml and do the job

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap ? (the issue might be 32-bit jvm)

Comment: What your system's configuration : 32bit or 64bit, windows, linux ... ?
On windows 32bit, even if you have 4g of ram available, [the jvm can't allocate more than 1.6g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit) .

Comment: 64bit 8GB Ram.. windows..

Comment: tried that already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap.. but no luck

Comment: Are you sure that the jvm is also 64bit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading the SoapUI 5.0.0 package for windows, I found out that in the file testrunner.bat there is a configuration at line 31 :

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties "-Dsoapui.home=%SOAPUI_HOME%\"
```

As you can see, the maximum memory parameter is set to 1024m (-Xmx1024m). Can you change it in your file to 2048m and try again.

Comment: I see in your question that you're using a 32bit SoapUI. So the testrunner.bat is probably using the jre shipped with soapui (C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\jre) which is 32bit.

Can you add this line just before the line I mentioned in my answer :


    set JAVA=PATH_TO_64BIT_JAVA_EXECUTABLE

Comment: I have updated in soapui.bat file which solves my issue.

Comment: Report comes as empty.. can you check that build.xml is correct?