# Cannot locate jruby during logstash installation

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, installation, logstash, jruby

I am learning something about ElasticSearch Stack and I am having a problem installing Logstash on Windows 10 (windows 10 enterprise N OS build 15063.674).

I installed ElasticSearch and Kibana and these are up and running.

I followed the steps on [this page](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash) to install Logstash:

*Step 1: Download and unzip Logstash*
downloaded "logstash-5.6.3.zip" file and unzipped it to: "c:\program files\elastic\"

*Step 2: Prepare a logstash.conf config file*
as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html), I created a "logstash-simple.conf" in the "c:\program files\elastic\logstash-5.6.3>" folder

*Step 3: Run bin/logstash -f logstash.conf*
at this point I am having the issue (I tried using both cmd and PowerShell with elevated privileges): the result is:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
"could not find jruby in C:\Program Files\Elastic\logstash-5.6.3\vendor\jruby"
```

Of course, the "vendor" folder exists, and there is a "jruby.bat" file inside. I searched the web and I found something about the JRUBY_BIN environment variable but event after the creation (and the additional reboot) the issue still is there.

Can someone address me to the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the `setup.bat` file before?

Comment: yes, I tried, the message is the same:

`PS C:\Program Files\Elastic\logstash-5.6.3> bin/setup.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.
"could not find jruby in C:\Program Files\Elastic\logstash-5.6.3\vendor\jruby"`

Comment: I reproduced the problem on my machine (same windows version, same logstash release, same install folder). The problem is the installation directory, perhaps the space in the path. I successfully logstash after moving the logstash folder in a path without space (`C:\Users\me\Downloads\logstash-5.6.3\ `)

Comment: you are right @baudsp thank you... moving from "program files" to "my" folder the jruby problem disappeared :-)

Comment: anyway, another problem happened :-(

`Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap`

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap, it seems it's a memory problem. I think the solution would be to set the option `-Xmx512m` in the file `logstash-5.6.3\config\jvm.options`

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-does-not-start-says-could-not-find-jruby-in/113500.
You can also try move logstash folder out of program files direct to C, it might help.

Comment: Please provide the solution as your answer. Links to external discussions tend to go stale over time.