# Java 32 bit cannot allocate jvm memory

Tags: java, heap-memory, 32-bit

my application is running over jdk 1.8 32 bit, windows 7. Recently we had few windows and mcafee updates.
I am using - xmx 1400m and - xms 1400m.
Once the updates have been installed, I started to have problems with running the application. Jvm says: VM
Could not reserve enough space for {size}KB object heap

Note that every 6 or 7 times it starts the application without error.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os?rq=1

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap