# error occurred during initialization of vm could not reserve enough space for object heap minecraft server

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I have 32G of ram on my desktop so I know the amount of ram isn't the issue but I keep getting the same error saying "error occurred during initialization of vm could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Maybe I'm not running 64bit java? How do I change that? My computer is 64bit.

java -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar server.jar nogui
pause

Comment: Could not reserve enough space for object heap - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap

Comment: The error could indicate you are using 32 bit Java, which can allocate +/- 1500MB on Windows.

Comment: Mark I started getting the error again and i was running at 1336. I thought that I made sure that I was running 64 bit. How would I check?

Answer (score 0):

Using `-Xmx3G` sets the maximum memory used by Java (and therefore Minecraft Server) to 3 GB.

To allow it to use more RAM (say, 5 GB), change the argument to `-Xmx`:

```sh
java -Xmx5G -Xms2G -jar server.jar nogui pause
```

Comment: java -Xmx5G -Xms2G -jar server.jar nogui
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx5G
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: -Xms1336m -Xmx1336m
made the server run again but i'd like to run with with more ram than that. I'm guessing that means I'm running with 32bit instead of 64bit but I don't know how to change that.