# Cannot get reserve enough space

Tags: android, gradle, command-prompt

I'm trying to run the command "gradlew.bat clean build" using the command prompt. But I'm getting an error,

*Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048M

Error occurred during initialization of VM

Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap*

Even if I increase the heap size from 2048 to 3048, I'm still getting the same error.

**Command Prompt**

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900]
> (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\PARAG>cd\

C:>cd\

C:>cd\Users\PARAG\AndroidStudioProjects\RotatableAutofitEditText-master\master\TurboCare

C:\Users\PARAG\AndroidStudioProjects\RotatableAutofitEditText-master\master\TurboCare>gradlew.bat clean build

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048M

Error occurred during initialization of VM

Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

C:\Users\PARAG\AndroidStudioProjects\RotatableAutofitEditText-master\master\TurboCare>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: You need to reduce heap size, not increase it.

Comment: Oh, will try this. Thank you.