# I am trying to setup a workspace for minecraft modding but when I run the command to setup the workspace it gives me a memory error?

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I was trying to setup my workspace for minecraft modding but when I ran the gradlew genEclipseRuns command to setup the files it gives me an error telling me that it is unable to start the daemon process. And also tells me that "Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap". The full error log is pasted below.

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -Xmx3G -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\coolc\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.4-bin\c0gwcg53nkjbqw7r0h0umtfvt\gradle-7.4\lib\gradle-launcher-7.4.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 7.4
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: You've installed 32-bit Java, as evidenced by the `(x86)` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`. Do you get the same error with 64-bit Java?

Comment: I did go through the Java 64-bit install process but I dont know if I installed the right one.

Comment: I went to (https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) to install 64-bit java.

Comment: I just fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I went to advanced system settings then I went to enviorment variables and changed my old 32 bit JAVA_HOME path to my new 64 bit Java path.