# Configuring ESA SNAP for Python not working due to memore issue

Tags: python, snap, sentinel2, s2, snap-python

I want to use ESA's SNAP Toolbox in Python and have done the following steps:

- Created a new python virtualenv called `snap` with Python 3.11.7
- Downloaded the latest SNAP release from https://step.esa.int/main/download/snap-download/
- Installed SNAP by executing the bash script with `sh esa-snap_sentinel_unix_9_0_0.sh`

I am now trying to configure SNAP for Python, following instructions in these tutorials:

- [Configure Python to use the SNAP-Python (snappy) interface (SNAP versions <= 9)](https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SNAP/pages/50855941/Configure+Python+to+use+the+SNAP-Python+snappy+interface+SNAP+versions+9)
- [Getting Started with SNAP Toolbox in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-snap-toolbox-in-python-89e33594fa04)

I keep encountering an error that I have not seen elsewhere yet

```
cd to_snap_installation/snap/bin
snappy-config path_to_venvs/virtualenvs/snap/python.exe
```

Gives the following error

> /mnt/eo-nas1/eoa-share/projects/010_CropCovEO/snap/bin/../platform/lib/nbexec: WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set
> Error occured during initialization of VM
> Could not reserve enough space for 369098752KB object heap

I have already tried to set the DISPLAY variable in my environment.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Could be related: [Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4401396/21350362)