# Running a play framework app in Amazon EC2 micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, playframework-2.0

I have a really basic play! app which simply handles a couple of normal GET and POST requests and talks to a MySQL database, nothing fancy.

I ran `play dist` and transferred the zip file to my EC2 instance. After unzipping it, going to the `bin` folder and running `./myapp`, I get a message:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Info: os::commit_memory ... error='Cannot allocate memory' (errorno=12)
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
```

I'm running Play version 2.2.1 and this instance has about 512MB of ram, with the 64-bit version of the Oracle JDK. Is this not enough to run a play! app or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: I've also tried running it using openjdk and got another similar error message: "Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Comment: Play can run with a small heap - have you tried a sample app create via play new with no changes?

Comment: You might also check out the bin script's options and allocate a smaller amount of memory.

Answer (score 13):

Play Framework 2.3 now has a nifty little feature.

```
$ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -mem 512 -J-server
```

Shoule get the job done.

Read http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3-SNAPSHOT/ProductionConfiguration

---

Specifying additional JVM arguments
You can specify any JVM arguments to the start script. Otherwise the default JVM settings will be used:

$ /path/to/bin/ -J-Xms128M -J-Xmx512m -J-server
As a convenience you can also set memory min, max, permgen and the reserved code cache size in one go; a formula is used to
determine these values given the supplied parameter (which represents maximum memory):

$ /path/to/bin/ -mem 512 -J-server

Comment: Thanks. worked for me on digital ocean 512 server with play2.3 (activator)

Comment: Note: This also works with activator! (`activator clean stage -mem 512`)

Answer (score 3):

Using **play 2.2.1** I had to run `play dist` to generate the zip file. Then I copied that to the aws instance.
Once there, I extracted the zip and changed the executable file:

from:

```
local mem=${1:-1024}
```

to:

```
local mem=${1:-512}
```

That did it for me. I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649517/play-framework-can-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap) but I didn't want to just delete the logic they had there, so I just reduced the default value.

Also please note that on aws ec2 micro:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.14) (amazon-65.1.11.14.57.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

So you have to use the same Java JDK when runnin `play dist`.

EDIT:

I updated java to **openjdk 7** and was able to run the sample play applications without any errors.

Comment: This worked like a charm, but is there a way to automate this process so one does not have to perform the edit with every update?

Comment: This works better - $ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -mem 512 -J-server